# How to check if an argument is equal to the name of a class attribute and return it?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Let's say we have the following function model_type:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn as sk
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import *

def model_type(linreg_model):
    for linreg_model in inspect.getmembers(sk.linear_model)
        return linreg_model()
model_type(ARDRegression) ##1
model_type(Lasso)         ##2
```

So the output I'm looking for is to return

1.

model_type(ARDRegression) = sk.linear_model.ARDRegression()

2.

model_type(Lasso) = sk.linear_model.Ridge()

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me, Sorry, so you want to know if your input argument `Bayesian` is the instance of sklearn model? or you want to pass a method as argument to the another method?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I’ve realized that my question is not the clearest.  

You’re correct I want to know if the input argument is the sklearn model and use linreg_model.fit/.predict etc instead of sklearn.linear_model.ARDRegression

Comment: Ok, in that case, you can send the method as an argument itself, if you send the correct method then you don't need to check, if it is the model type that you wanted, and can proceed calling the `predict`, if that is not the case, it could be checked with the proper instance type.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Please have a look at the updated edit it could illustrate better what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Please note 'Bayesian' does not exist in sklearn.linear_model

Example: (should work as is)

```py
import inspect
import sys
from sklearn import linear_model 

def get_model(key):
    for x in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules['sklearn.linear_model']):
      if isinstance(x, tuple) and x[0] == key:
        return x[1]()
    raise KeyError(key)
```

```
>>> print(get_model('BayesianRidge'))
<class 'sklearn.linear_model._bayes.BayesianRidge'>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t output what I have in mind. I want to use the function to determine the model type and use my function as a generic function to recall the input model functions.

Comment: I don't understand. Did you mean `model_type('Bayesian')` instead of `model_type(Bayesian)` ? Please review my answer, I edited it according to my assumption

Comment: I've changed the body of the main question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @AliJ did you try the new code? Did it work as expected ?

Comment: Thank you so much Alexandre for your time and continuous help. Unfortunately it didn't work. I want to recall the class of the linear_model matching the key or argument.

Comment: @AliJ this code works now, I tested it on my computer and on a google colab environment